# Unity rotating sprite on Y axis is off kilter in game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a sprite in a 2d platformer that I have applied rotation to. It is rotating 0 to 360 degrees on the Y axis only. It looks correct in the Scene tab. When I switch to the Game tab, the rotation axis is off kilter.

[Here's a gif of it, and an image of the current camera inspector values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQA6V.jpg)

I've tried all options for the rotation interpolation. Additionally, if I apply similar rotation to the X or Z axes, they operate as expected. My best guess is that it's some sort of camera issue, but I really don't know.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your camera's inspector configuration

Comment: added camera inspector config to the same image album link.

Comment: Sorry, I should have maybe been more specific. Is that at runtime?   Anyway, You should try setting your camera to use "Orthographic" mode instead of "Perspective". Your scene view is in Orthographic mode (one of the things that 2D mode does).